# How many child records can a parent cascade delete (documented limit)?

Tags: batch, governorlimits, dml, cascadedelete

I have a `CustomObject__c` which has childrens **2 level deep**. Together a single parent object can have **many 10.000 child records**.

[image]

Would it work to auto-delete the thousands ob child records just using a `cascade-delete` on the parent or should I use a **Batch deletion**?

I found many similar question on SFSE and the web but none really answered this question: is there a documented limit.

Comment: I would expect it to have the general limit of 10k rows per transaction, but am interested if this is different.

Comment: did you look at sfdcfox - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/178080/2602

Comment: check this - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8869/master-detail-relationship-limit