# Enable Batch Apex process several records for related objects

Tags: soql, batch, governorlimits

I'm trying to write a batch class that operates on ***2 related objects(Course__c and CourseDetail__c in a master detail relationship)*** and this batch has to look for all the child records of each parent record, then converts them in to a json format which will then be inserted in a long text field of the parent record (the goal is to compress the child records in json format then after i'll delete all the child records).

If some parent records have  more than 50 million child records, others 30 million child records and others less than 50 000 child records  how can i process them ?

(i will modify the objects to Faculty__c and CourseDetail__c since the first relationship is a bit strange to consider that a parent can have sevral records)

I had the idea of querying  all the parent records in the start method and in the execute method use a subquery to re extract all parent records together with it's child records, then loop on them to build my json string, but i guest the govenor limit will be an issue here.

here is my code:

```
public without sharing class CompressCourseDetailBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful{
    
    //start method to collect all courses
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){

        
        return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Id FROM Course__c');
    }

    //execute method to compress course details of a course in json then adds it to the json value field of the parent record
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Course__c> scope){

        //query for all data using a sub query
        List<Course__c> courses = [SELECT Id, Compression_State__c, JsonValue__c, (SELECT Id, Name, CourseId__c, Teacher_Name__c, Faculty__c, Number_of_Student__c, To_Archive__c FROM CourseDetails__r WHERE Number_of_Student__c != 0) FROM Course__c WHERE Id in: scope];

        for (Course__c course: courses) {
            //json string for all compressed child records
            String jsondata='';

            //update compression state

            course.Compression_State__c = 'Compressed';

            //json generator object
            JSONGenerator jsongen = JSON.createGenerator(true);

            //start generating json
            jsongen.writeStartObject();
            jsongen.writeStringField('Course__c', course.Id);

            for(CourseDetail__c coursedetail : course.CourseDetails__r){

                jsongen.writeFieldName(coursedetail.Name);
                jsongen.writeStartObject();
                jsongen.writeStringField('Teacher_Name__c', coursedetail.Teacher_Name__c);
                jsongen.writeStringField('Faculty__c', coursedetail.Faculty__c);
                jsongen.writeNumberField('Number_of_Student__c', coursedetail.Number_of_Student__c);
                jsongen.writeBooleanField('To_Archive__c', coursedetail.To_Archive__c);
                jsongen.writeEndObject();
            }


            //end of json generation
            jsongen.writeEndObject();
            jsondata = jsongen.getAsString();
            //update json value field with compressed data
            course.JsonValue__c = jsondata;
        }
      Database.update(courses);
    }

    //finish method
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){

    }
}
```

Comment: With over 50 million children, you have completely blown [recommended limits](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8869/master-detail-relationship-limit). I would think your org performance will be terrible. Are you simply trying to keep counts here? I.e. the `Number_of_student__c`? If you care only about a count, would an aggregate query work for you?

Comment: Also, if you only need counts for archiving purposes, could you introduce incremental counting as part of your data archival process?

Comment: @phil W No i don't need to keep counts, i just want to collect all the child records and convert them in a json format.  i knew  the limit will be exceeded with my approach. I don't know if there is a better approach to solve the issue?

Comment: The JSON would not fit in a large text area anyway since that is at most 128Kb long. If you have 50m children, you would get 0.002 characters per child.

Comment: ok i see. So if the 10 000 limit for the master detail relationship is respected , it means this solution will work perfectly fine. but just one last question if i found myself in a situation where i need to process child records of a parent record in a batch, are there any best practices to handle these data and avoid using sub query within the execute method?

Comment: You do not need a sub query, just another query for the data to process related to those from the `start` query.

Comment: okay, thank you for the help.

Comment: BTW with 10000 records, you get 13 characters per record only.

Comment: yes you are right i read the documentation and the limit for the long text area is 128kb so for 10000 child record, each child should generate maximum 13 characters.